# Content generated with Javascript ignores CSS classes?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a simple memory game generated by Javascript. The idea is to create 24 buttons in 4 rows with 6 buttons each. To do this, I'm using the following code:

```
function shuffle(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}

var buttons = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24];

function playGame(){
    shuffle(buttons);

    for(i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        document.write("<a href='#' class='btn_Numbers'>" + buttons[i] + "</a>");
        if(i == 5 || i == 11 || i == 17 || i == 23){
            document.write('<br />');
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine, except that the generated hyperlinks completely ignore the CSS class `btn_Numbers`. When I write such a hyperlink manually, it works perfectly.

I have a feeling that this is caused because the CSS was loaded before the content exists. I vaguely remember something like this happened to me before a few years ago. But I really can't remember how to fix the problem. So any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show where you included the stylesheet `link` in your html, and how `btn_Numbers` is supposed to be styled?

Comment: No, that's not the case. Chances are, using `document.write` removes everything else on your page (including your stylesheets) so it doesn't look like your CSS gets applied, but in reality, there is no CSS because calling `document.write` removed it.

Comment: I think you're right about that @Adam. Sure I can do that Josh but I think Adam is right about the problem.

Comment: @Adam Ye you were right. Used `innerHTML` instead and that solved the problem inmediately. Thanks a lot! If you want, please turn your comment into an answer so I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not the case. Using document.write removes everything else on your page (including your stylesheets) so while it doesn't look like your CSS gets applied, it's because there is no CSS because calling `document.write` removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to add links to your HTML without removing everything else with document.write:

```
var elm = document.getElementById("someID");
var link = document.createNode("a");

link.text = "Some text"
link.setAttribute("class", "btn_Numbers");
link.setAttribute("href", "#");

elm.appendChild(link)
```

The code above will append the node you have created to you page without removing anything else.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote for a good attempt at an answer. But personally I disagree about using this because you always want your scripts to run as fast as possible with as less resources as possible. Your code will be more cpu intensive than is nessesary in this case. Aside from that, I have a feeling this script will cause issues when used in a loop. But I'm not sure about that.